# Is the principle of mathematical induction a purely logic statement?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics

Mathematical induction states that if a proposition P(0) is true, and if the implication P(n) ⇒
P(n+1) is true, then it must be the case that P(n) is true for all natural numbers n.

My main question is, is this a logical truth in the same way modus ponens is a logical truth? If not, what are the arguments? Has this been discussed in the literature in philosophy and mathematics?

My intuition says that mathematical induction is so basic, that a rejection of it would amount to a rejection of logic. However, from what I can tell, the principle of induction is one axiom of the Peano axioms used to characterize the natural number system. If I'm not mistaken the consensus is that once you are talking about natural numbers as mathematical objects, you are outside the strict domain of logic. Equivalently, you can consider starting with ZFC set theory, and then leverage the axiom of infinity to prove the principle of mathematical induction, but again, once you are talking about ZFC set theory, you are dealing with sets, which are outside logic in the strict sense.

On this account, if we want mathematical induction to have the same status as modus ponens, then we'd have to say that natural numbers or sets are objects of logic, which would amount of logicism. Thus, a rejection of logicism means mathematical induction is not a logical statement (in the strict sense)? Am I correct in this thinking? I am curious to see what other people have said on this matter.

This question might be a matter of semantics, because we'd have to delineate what exact is logic and what exact is mathematics, so hopefully that can be clarified as well if necessary.

Comment: Induction is not part of the logic, it is an axiom of a theory (or possibly a theorem). It couldn't be part of the logic, because it only applies to sets of things with a "next" function of some sort. Logic applies to everything.

Comment: Saying that natural numbers or sets are objects of logic does not amount to logicism, logicism is a much stronger claim that all mathematical truths are derivable from logic. The substantive fact is that induction is not derivable from laws typically called "logical". If one wishes to add something to them so that it becomes derivable and still call the result "logic", like [neo-logicists](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logicism/), they are free to do that. What "logic" means changed a lot since Aristotle, and may change again. So this is just a debate about words with no substance to it.

Comment: I think you formulated the principle as modus ponens in your first sentence? Modulo going to infnity. It looks like an infinite succession of modus ponens to me

Comment: No it is not. It is the fundamental axiom of arithmetic, defining the "essential property" of the natural numbers sequence.

Comment: See Henri Poincaré, [Sur la nature du raisonnement mathématique (1894)](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/La_Science_et_l%E2%80%99Hypoth%C3%A8se/Chapitre_1) and also J.Boniface, [Poincaré et le principe d’induction](https://www.erudit.org/fr/revues/philoso/2004-v31-n1-philoso741/008937ar.pdf)

Comment: @Conifold I thought by being universal logic and thus modus ponens should be valid wherever induction is valid? Or does it not work quite like that? At least any valid derivation via induction must be valid MP right? Does MP have valid deductions that aren’t valid in induction then?

Comment: @JKusin Induction requires more expressive machinery than MP to even be formulated. It is inexpressible in propositional logic or pure predicate calculus, for example, because they do not include natural numbers. Valid deductions there cannot be "valid in induction" simply because there is no such thing as induction.

Comment: @Conifold What about people who think MP just is universal, forget different logics for a second because I'm not sure what that's adding or if they take away MP being universal. By being universal it can handle any case where the premises and conclusion have clear truth values, and is s.t. the conclusion must be true if the premises are true. I think all the statements/cases induction functions on must have clear truth values, or induction wouldn't be used. So ALL cases of induction can be handed to MP with this simple argument. Should I ask this as its own question, is it nonsense?

Comment: @JKusin I am getting the feeling that you are talking not about *mathematical* induction but rather just iterated MP. The difference is that mathematical induction gives you an infinite sequence of statements at once (wrapped into a single universal statement) and you cannot get there by iterating MP. This is not about clarity of truth values, non-universal MP or different logics.

Comment: Long story short: you're right that induction is basic, but it's not "the most basic". And in fact, what happens if we take all the usual axioms of arithmetic, except induction, has been studied. Also what happens if we replace induction by something else, for a few somethings.

Comment: @Conifold I'm not trying to iterate MP. I'm more noticing MP doesn't stipulate deductive support of premises to be true. Non-iterated MP: P1: Base case about particular integer is true, P2: Each case implies the case about the next integer is true, C: all enumerated cases are true. On what grounds are we rejecting P2 (here it's stated w/o using math induction)? Compare P1: X is a region of space. P2: Each region implies there is a further region of space C: all regions of space have further regions of space. We can know each P2 intuitively/non-deductively & their MP's give 'wrapped up' at once

Comment: @JKusin What you described *does* use (math) induction. P1 and P2 do not imply C by MP alone even if it seems so "intuitively". Your P2 does not have "all enumerated cases" in the consequent, and so MP can never derive that. Nor can you get it by conjoining what MP does give you in steps finitely many times (this is what I called "iterated MP"). Try to write it symbolically, and you'll see. The reason is that "all enumerated cases" may not be exhausted by those you get (implicitly) iterating "to the next integer". This is exactly what happens in models of arithmetic w/o induction.

Comment: @Conifold you’re right I struggled and failed to implement MP correctly, even after you gave me ample opportunity to try. Ugh I hate wasting your time like that. Sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Peano's Axioms the principle of mathematical induction (PMI) can be stated as follows:

> For all subsets *P* of ***N***, if 0 in *P* and for all *x* in *P*, we
> have the successor of *x* also in ***N***, then *P* = ***N***,
> where ***N*** is the set of natural numbers.

This is *not* an axiom of logic. There are no sets and subsets in the axioms of logic.(Older versions of Peano's Axioms do not use the notation of set theory.) Each of Peano's Axioms, including PMI, can be derived from the axioms of set theory and logic.

Equivalently, PMI might be stated more intuitively as follows:

> For every natural number n (except for 0), it is possible to reach n
> by a process of repeated succession starting at 0.
>
> 0 --> 1 --> 2 --> 3 --> ... --> n

It is possible to formally prove this equivalence. (Not trivial. It can be done in 228 lines using a form of natural deduction.)

Comment: thank you diar Dan, i don't have to wright this answer with a broken Eng and village logic

Answer (score 4):

There is a strong relationship (not an identity) between transfinite induction and the foundation axiom, in that foundation "streamlines" the process of attempting such an induction, if I remember correctly. But then the foundation axiom is not logically absolute in that there is no *logical* impossibility in figuring the elementhood relation in ill-founded patterns.

Alternatively, to figure it so would mean referring, instead, to different types of elementhood relation. But then where do these types come from? They *look* like types of epistemic logic, of patterns in the regress of epistemic reasoning. Does this make them logicism-friendly grounds for set theory? It is hard to tell, perhaps, where things like temporal epistemic logic mutate into Brouwer-flavored intuitionism (with time as the relevant intuition and an LEM-unfriendly standard of inference in the background), or where belief that abstract mathematical objects are purely possible objects (in a nonactualist zone) is or is not functionally equivalent to claiming that mathematical objects are fictional objects. And so if the boundaries between logicist-style descriptions of mathematical objects and set-theorist such descriptions are not too sharp (especially when we factor in the wide array of considerations about what "logic" is), some of the significance of the whole framework (of this question, of logical vs. mathematical concepts) seems to break down. The induction principle seems to direct us to infer a conclusion in a universally reliable way from a given pair of premise-types: why would this inference type count as less "purely logical" than the *modus ponens* inference type?

So: superficially, the principle of mathematical induction is not a generic principle of inference, and in that sense is not "purely logical." But since there is no especially stable theory about when an inference relation is "purely logical" in that levels of generality can not always be well-sorted into an absolute representation on our side of our own cognition, then it seems possible to characterize the notion of well-foundedness as a matter of general epistemic logic (the *k*-operator/term being defined explicitly in relation to the question of the epistemic regress, not just in some "justified true belief + *x*" kind of way). And the question of whether logic is properly-speaking "knowable," and if so, how we know whether a claim in our theory of generic inference is true, seems to "generalize over" logic in some capacity, still from a logical vantage (and so we have inescapable circularity or coherentism in our dialectic, here, which gets at the issue of whether circular reasoning is always flawed, and if not, when/how).

Comment: This is a bit above my head. Can one carry out induction so instead of a linear sequence, there might be a bifurcation, such as in a lattice such as the poset of lattice points on the Cartesian plane? We have induction over the naturals as part of PA, transfinite induction using sets as elements in our logic, is there some sort of taxonomy on these sorts of abstract objects? Like, can we have an infinite binary tree?

Comment: @JD the phrase "infinite binary tree" sounds like something I've seen in essays on tree theory, and Peter Koellner, for instance, says that normal/ZFC set theory can be reworded as "a theory of well-founded trees," but I've never been able to get a good grip on tree theory. At one point I was under the impression that it generalizes over the notion of the hyperoperator sequence in arithmetic, but I haven't been able to confirm that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to take a different tack than the other responses and follow the Philosophy of Language. Simply put, since the time of Frege, meaning has been posited to be compositional, that is to say, when you have a proposition, it can be broken into smaller pieces of meaning. This is the [principle of compositionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_compositionality), and is hardly a radical statement, as sentences are made out of lexemes (think words and phrases that comprise clauses and sentences) and lexemes are composed of morphemes (concepts of affixes and stems that compose words).

So, let's decompose the inductive principle. I'm going to use the WP logic from their article on mathematical induction. It's:

> ∀k(P(k) -> P(k+1))

Is this logical or mathematical or both? Well, first note that k seems to have a domain of discourse implied, that of the naturals, and that to express the idea that we are moving from a term to a successor, arithmetic addition is used. Is that component of the statement enough to say that in some sense this is both a logical and an arithmetic statement? I'd say yes. Adding and subtracting are as plain as we can get in math. And yet, we can write this with successor notation instead:

> ∀k(P(k) -> P(s(k))

Read, for all elements in a sequence, given some element predicated in a domain of discourse, there is another element in the sequence that is a successor or follows the prior element. We've just made the addition disappear!

But note that the sentence doesn't include the existential quantification operator. We could write:

> ∃k,s(k)∈P ∀k(P(k) -> P(s(k))

Now, note that existential quantification implies the cardinality of P must be at least 2, since we have k, and s(k) at a minimum. So does the very act of creating and binding any logic variable presume cardinality, and thus the mathematical act of counting exists? I'd say yes.

Thus, the notion that one can have logic statements free of math seems a bit suspect. Even if we eliminate using the naturals as subscripts (note that [index sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_set) are generally bound to natural numbers to indicate sequence, and that a sequence is often defined as a one-to-one mapping to the naturals), we still have variables which have cardinality, an ontological point that Quine defended. The very act of having logic variables bound to a domain of discourse seems to require that counting and cardinality are inextricably tied up as conceptual components.

If one takes the principle of compositionality seriously, and one parses apart logical statements, it seem inevitable that mathematics is indivisible at a fundamental level if counting is considered mathematics. From a [mathematical intuitionist standpoint (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuitionism/), a la Brouwer and those who follow, logic statements are necessarily composed of primitives from both mathematics (counting and numbers) and logic (predication, grouping, entailment). Thus, there is no tidy line between math and logic. Maybe why [mathematical logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_logic) is so fruitful, and why there are isomorphisms between computer science, mathematics, and logical forms via the [Curry-Howard-Lambek correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence).